# What's the lowest browser versions ATK4 should be compatible with?

Tags: atk4, php

What's the lowest browser versions ATK4 user interface should be compatible with?

I'm especially interested in supported Internet Explorer versions. I see that in Chrome and FireFox everything looks quite ok, but in IE8 I have quite many visual defects. I'm not sure it it's the same in IE9. I'm not talking about rounded borders or things like that, but about all page (almost) default layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, basically you should consider following:

1) default theme uses some css2/3 tricks to enable nicer ui. there is however backward compatibility for ui for ie 8.0 not sure about lower  versions. obviously, there will be some degradation in look and feel the further you go away from modern browser

2) atk4 uses jquery for js event handling, so you should consult jquery & jquery ui to see what exactly is supported.

Agile Toolkit itself can be used with no javascript at all and with plain simple design theme which you can create yourself.

so summarizing -  agile toolkit does not imply any restrictions to browser used, rather it's up to you to decide which features are necessary for you and which browsers and versions are okay for you - combination of that will answer your question.

p.s. atk4 can even  be used as plain CLI (command line interface), with no html/js at all,  but still would provide with all mvc, business logic, etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer.


I know I can change/overwrite/extend everything in ATK4. I was just wondering maybe there is some "bottom line" drawn by Romans & Co about browser compatibility.
For example, every template/component/view implemented into default ATK4 package should look and work OK (with only small visual glitches, like no rounded corners in IE) on at least the following browsers/versions ...

Comment: I think we do support IE8, but it's really up to the theme. Our approach is that we prefer to use degradation where IE8 might look less impressive (like no rounded corners), but would still be functional. If you find any major glitches, I would appreciate a suggestion on how to fix it.

Comment: as I mentioned, it all depends on your UI requirements. there are no predefined constraints within Atk which makes it perfect to use in most of situations. As Romaninsh notes, there is reasonable degradation, if browser is not capable enough. Even links would fall back to non-ajax if browser does not have JS enabled.

Comment: DarkSide i've Done some testing - if your question is regarding the default theme then I can tell you it doesn't work in IE7. Otherwise as both roman and @jancha mentioned you can use the templates in a manner which makes it work. As for jQuery - well it will work all the way down to IE6 for now for more info: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-more-about-jquerys-web-browser-compatibility.